# using nokia location api from a normal application (non-phone)

Tags: java, geolocation, nokia

Does Nokia provide any direct location based api where we can pass longitude and latitude and get the exact address/location in response ?. I am developing a **general/non-phone** java application which runs on a server.

Thanks and Regards
Raaghu.K

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could have a look at the **Places API** (http://developer.here.net/places) available in the docs. Strictly speaking, it is *not* a geocoding API, but passing a `latitude` and `longitude` in your search will return results that have a `vicinity` parameter that may suit your need, as per their description :

> *The textual description of the location of the place; usually derived from the address of the place, but may also contain any other description that helps a user understand where the place is located.*

You can see the related documentation page here :

- Search : http://developer.here.net/docs/places/topics/resource-search.html
- Results : http://developer.here.net/docs/places/topics/media-type-search.html

Hope it helps !

**EDIT :**
Here is a sample call from the docs : http://demo.places.nlp.nokia.com/places/v1/discover/explore?at=52.53099%2C13.38455%3Bu%3D1000&size=0&app_id=_peU-uCkp-j8ovkzFGNU&app_code=gBoUkAMoxoqIWfxWA5DuMQ&accept=application/json

Comment: Thanks for your reply, **Places API** wont actually give u any url which I can use...

Comment: I've edited my answer to include a sample call to the REST api - is it what you're looking for ? I reckon the official documentation is not up-to-date on the API urls